Pytorch Reinforcement Learning Agent dont work an i dont know why really need some Tips
SO i Try to Implement an Reinforcement Agent for the Steam game (Resident Evil 4 2005 Version) .I wrote this Code but i am absolutely frustrated because he only doing some crap or didnt even move at all , i changed the getobs() function and now he doesnt move at all . I couldnt figure out what to do for Months and i really need some help here
Here is my Code:
import os

import torch as T
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import numpy as np
from pynput.keyboard import Controller, Key
import os
import cv2
from typing import TypeVar, Tuple , Dict
import time
import pyautogui
import pygetwindow as gw
import time
class MainNetwork(nn.Module):

def __init__(self, model_path , checkpoint_path , n_actions , lr , input_dims):
    super().__init__()

    self.chekpoint_dir = checkpoint_path
    self.file = os.path.join(self.chekpoint_dir , model_path)

    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(input_dims[0] , 64 , 8 , 2 , 2)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(64 , 64 , 8 , 2 , 2)
    self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64 , 64 , 8 , 2 , 2)

    self.activation = nn.PReLU()
    self.optim = optim.Adam(self.parameters()  , lr = lr)
    self.loss = nn.MSELoss()
    self.device = T.device("cuda" if T.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    
    comp = self.comp_in_dims(input_dims)

    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(comp , 1024)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1024 , 512)
    self.A = nn.Linear(512 , n_actions)
    self.V = nn.Linear(512 , 1)

def forward(self , state):
    
    print(state)

    X = self.activation(self.conv1(state))
    X2 = self.activation(self.conv2(X))
    X3 = self.activation(self.conv3(X2))

    flatten = X3.view(X2.size()[0] , -1)

    A = self.fc1(flatten)
    V = self.fc2(A)

    return V , A

def comp_in_dims(self, input_dims):

    dummy = T.zeros(1 , *input_dims)
    dims = self.conv1(dummy)
    dims = self.conv2(dims)
    dims = self.conv3(dims)

    return int(np.prod(dims.shape[1:]))

def saving_model(self):
    print("... saving in progress ...")
    T.save(self.state_dict() , self.chekpoint_dir)

def loading_mode_state_dict(self):
    print("... loading in progress ... ")
    self.load_state_dict(T.load(self.chekpoint_dir))

class ReplayBuffer():
def __init__(self , max_buffer_size , lr , in_dims , n_actions):
    self.max = max_buffer_size
    self.mem_cntr = 0

    self.state_memory = np.zeros((self.max, *in_dims) , dtype = np.float32)
    self.update_state_memory =np.zeros((self.max, *in_dims) , dtype = np.float32)

    self.action_memory = np.zeros((self.max,) ,dtype= np.int32)
    self.reward_memory = np.zeros((self.max,) , dtype = np.float32)
    self.terminal_memory = np.zeros((self.max,) , dtype = bool)

def sample_batches(self , state , update , n_actions , rewards , done):

    X = self.mem_cntr % self.max 

    self.state_memory[X] = state
    self.update_state_memory[X] = update
    self.action_memory[X] = n_actions
    self.reward_memory[X] = rewards
    self.terminal_memory[X] = done

    self.mem_cntr += 1

def batch_memory(self , batch_size):

    max_ = max(self.mem_cntr , self.max )
    rnd = np.random.choice(max_ , batch_size , replace= False)

    state = self.state_memory[rnd]
    update =self.update_state_memory[rnd]
    n_actions = self.action_memory[rnd]
    rewards = self.reward_memory[rnd]
    terminal = self.terminal_memory[rnd]

    return state , update , n_actions , rewards , terminal

class Agent():

def __init__(self , lr , input_dims , n_actions ,  max_buffer_size , batch_size ,
             replace = 1000 , eps = 1.0 , eps_dec = 1e-3 , eps_min = 1e-2 , gamma = 0.99,
             model_path = None , chechpoint_path = None):
    self.lr = lr
    self.input_dims = input_dims
    self.n_actions= n_actions
    self.max_buffer_size = max_buffer_size
    self.eps = eps
    self.eps_dec = eps_dec
    self.eps_min = eps_min
    self.gamma = gamma 
    self.model_path = model_path
    self.chechpoint_path = chechpoint_path 
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.action_space = [i for i in range(self.n_actions)]
    self.replace_target_network = replace
    self.learn_rate_step_size = 0
    
    self.memory = ReplayBuffer(
        in_dims= self.input_dims,
        max_buffer_size= self.max_buffer_size,
        lr = self.lr,
        n_actions= self.n_actions)
    
    self.Main_Network = MainNetwork(
        model_path= self.model_path,
        checkpoint_path=self.chechpoint_path,
        n_actions= self.n_actions,
        lr=self.lr,
        input_dims=self.input_dims)
    
    self.Target_Network = MainNetwork(
        model_path= self.model_path,
        checkpoint_path=self.chechpoint_path,
        n_actions= self.n_actions,
        lr=self.lr,
        input_dims=self.input_dims)
    
def choose_actions(self, observations):
    if np.random.random() > self.eps:
        np_arr = np.array([observations], dtype=np.float32)  
        arr_to_tensor = T.tensor(np_arr).to(self.Main_Network.device)

        with T.no_grad(): 
            V, advantages = self.Main_Network.forward(arr_to_tensor)

        Q_values = V + (advantages - advantages.mean(dim=1, keepdim=True))
        actions = T.argmax(Q_values, dim=1).item() 
    else:
        actions = np.random.choice(self.action_space)

    return actions

def dec_eps(self):

    self.eps = self.eps - self.eps_dec if self.eps > self.eps_min else self.eps_min

def replace_target_network_fun(self):

    if self.Target_Network is not None and \
    self.replace_target_network % self.learn_rate_step_size == 0:
        self.Target_Network.load_state_dict(self.Main_Network.state_dict())

def sample_obs_batches(self, state , update , n_actions , rewards , done):

    self.memory.sample_batches(state , update , n_actions , rewards , done)

def sample_Main_batches(self):

    state , update , n_actions , rewards , done = self.memory.batch_memory(self.batch_size)

    states = T.tensor(state).to(self.Main_Network.device)
    updates = T.tensor(update).to(self.Main_Network.device)
    n_action = T.tensor(n_actions).to(self.Main_Network.device)
    reward = T.tensor(rewards).to(self.Main_Network.device)
    terminal = T.tensor(done).to(self.Main_Network.device)

    return states , updates , n_action , reward , terminal

def learn(self):
    if self.memory.mem_cntr < self.batch_size:
        return

    self.replace_target_network_fun()

    # Extrahiere die Batches
    states, next_states, actions, rewards, dones = self.sample_Main_batches()

    # Vorhersage für aktuelle Zustände
    V_s, A_s = self.Main_Network.forward(states)
    Q_pred = V_s + (A_s - A_s.mean(dim=1, keepdim=True))
    Q_pred = Q_pred.gather(1, actions.unsqueeze(-1)).squeeze(-1)

    # Vorhersage für nächste Zustände
    V_s_next, A_s_next = self.Target_Network.forward(next_states)
    Q_next = V_s_next + (A_s_next - A_s_next.mean(dim=1, keepdim=True))
    Q_next_max = Q_next.max(dim=1)[0]
    Q_next_max[dones] = 0.0  # Terminalzustände haben keine zukünftigen Belohnungen

    # Zielwerte berechnen
    Q_target = rewards + self.gamma * Q_next_max

    # Verlustfunktion berechnen
    loss = self.Main_Network.loss(Q_target, Q_pred)

    # Backpropagation
    self.Main_Network.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    self.Main_Network.optim.step()

    # Epsilon-Wert für Exploration reduzieren
    self.dec_eps()

class Actions():
WALK_FORWARD = 0
WALK_BACKWARD = 1
AIM = 2
SHOOT = 3
RELOAD = 4
TURN_AROUND_FAST = 5

class ResidentEvilEnv:
ObsType = TypeVar("ObsType")
ActType = TypeVar("ActType")

def __init__(self):
    self.actions = {
        Actions.WALK_FORWARD: self.walking_forward,
        Actions.WALK_BACKWARD: self.walking_backward,
        Actions.AIM: self.aim,
        Actions.SHOOT: self.shoot,
        Actions.RELOAD : self.reload,
        Actions.TURN_AROUND_FAST : self.turn_around_fast}
    
    self.health = 100
    self.enemies_defeated = 0
    self.keyboard = Controller()

def step(self, action: ActType) -> Tuple[ObsType, float, bool, Dict]:

    if action in self.actions:
        self.actions[action]()
        observation = self.getObs()  

        reward = self.calculate_reward() 

        done = self.check_done()  
        
        return observation, reward, done, {}
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Unbekannte Aktion: {action}")
    
def check_done(self):
    if self.health <= 0:
        return True
    return False

def enemy_defeated(self):
    self.enemies_defeated += 1
    print(f"Feind besiegt! Anzahl besiegter Feinde: {self.enemies_defeated}")

def calculate_reward(self) -> float:
    reward = 0

    reward += self.enemies_defeated  

    if self.health < 100:
        reward -= (100 - self.health)  

    return reward

def perform_action(self, action: Actions):

    if action in self.actions:
        self.actions[action]()
    else:
        print(f"Unbekannte Aktion: {action}")

def perform_action(self, action: Actions):
    if action in self.actions:
        self.actions[action]()
    else:
        print(f"Unbekannte Aktion: {action}")

def walking_forward(self):
    print("Gehe vorwärts")
    self.keyboard.press('w')
    time.sleep(0.1)
    self.keyboard.release('w')

def walking_backward(self):
    print("Gehe rückwärts")
    self.keyboard.press('s')
    time.sleep(0.1)
    self.keyboard.release('s')

def aim(self):
    print("Zielen")
    self.keyboard.press(Key.left)  # Beispiel für das Drücken einer Maustaste
    time.sleep(0.1)
    self.keyboard.release(Key.left)

def shoot(self):
    print("Schießen")
    self.enemy_defeated()
    self.keyboard.press(Key.right)  # Beispiel für das Drücken einer Maustaste
    time.sleep(0.1)
    self.keyboard.release(Key.right)

def reload(self):
    print("Reload")
    self.aim()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    self.keyboard.press('r')
    time.sleep(0.1)
    self.keyboard.release('r')

def turn_around_fast(self):
    print("TURN_AROUND_FAST")
    self.keyboard.press('s')
    self.keyboard.release('s')
    time.sleep(0.1)
    self.keyboard.release('s')

def getObs(self):

    while True:
        Screen = pyautogui.screenshot()
        NpArr = np.array(Screen)
        CropScreen = NpArr[:1100 , 500: , :]
        Shape = CropScreen.shape
        CorrectColor = cv2.cvtColor(CropScreen  , cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        cv2.imshow("ResidentEvil 4" , CorrectColor)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF==ord("q"):
            break 

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return Shape

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.actions)

def focus_game_window(self):
    window = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('Resident Evil 4')[0] 
    window.activate()
    time.sleep(1) 

if name == "main":
env = ResidentEvilEnv()

agent = Agent(lr=1e-3,
              input_dims= env.getObs(),
              n_actions = env.__len__(),
              max_buffer_size= 10000,
              batch_size= 200,
              replace= 1000,
              eps= 1.0,
              eps_dec = 1e-3,
              gamma= 0.99,
              model_path= r"I:\Sonstiges\Programmieren\Machine Learning\Part 6 - Reinforcement Learning",
              chechpoint_path= r"I:\Sonstiges\Programmieren\Machine Learning\Part 6 - Reinforcement Learning")

rewards = []
game_iters = 1000
scores = []
env.focus_game_window()

for i in range(game_iters):

    done = False

    truncated = False
    score = 0

    obs = env.getObs()

while not done and not truncated:
    actions = agent.choose_actions(obs)
    observation_, reward, done, info = env.step(actions)
    print(f"Aktion: {actions}, Belohnung: {reward}, Fertig: {done}")

    # Übergabe an den Replay Buffer
    agent.sample_obs_batches(obs, observation_, actions, reward, done)

    # Aktualisiere den Zustand für die nächste Iteration
    obs = observation_

    # Lerne aus den gesammelten Erfahrungen
    agent.learn()

*My Old get obs function was this: *
def getObs(self):

screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
img_array = np.array(screenshot)
if len(img_array.shape) == 3 and img_array.shape[-1] == 3:

    img_array = cv2.cvtColor(img_array, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
else:
    print(f"Unerwartete Anzahl an Kanälen: {img_array.shape[-1]}")
img_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (84, 84))
img_array = img_array / 255.0  
img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)
img_display = img_array[0] 
cv2.imshow('Screen Capture', img_display)
cv2.waitKey(1) 
print(img_array.shape)
return img_array

